# Z3 bug in substitution

Tags: java, z3, substitution, smt

I used the Z3 Java API of expr.Substitute(Expr[] oldArgs, Expr[] newArgs), and got stuck. Wondering if there's a bug in the substitution process.

Here's some declarations:

```
(declare-const addr_of_s (_ BitVec 16))
(declare-const m_10 (Array (_ BitVec 16) (_ BitVec 16)))
(declare-const size_10 (Array (_ BitVec 16) (_ BitVec 16)))
(declare-const pre_disjoint_10 Bool)
(declare-fun disjoint_10 ((_ BitVec 16) (_ BitVec 16)) Bool)
(declare-const label (_ BitVec 16))
(declare-const label_0 (_ BitVec 16))
```

This is the expression to be substituted:

```
(= (select m_10 (bvadd addr_of_s (bvmul #x0003 #x0001))) #x0000)
```

oldArgs: `{m_10, size_10, pre_disjoint_10}`

newArgs:

```
{(store (store (store (store m_10 addr_of_s #x0031)
                 (bvadd #x0001 addr_of_s)
                 #x0032)
          (bvadd #x0002 addr_of_s)
          #x0033)
   addr_of_s
   #x0032),

size_10,

(and pre_disjoint_10 
     (disjoint_10 label label_0) 
     (bvuge (bvadd label label_0) label)
     (not (= label #x0000)))}
```

Comment: It seems to have a non-terminate code there.

Comment: Are you using the latest "unstable" version of Z3? In case you are able to create a repro could you post it as a bug on z3.codeplex.com?

Comment: @NikolajBjorner Solved with latest version of Z3